# Why am I getting the following output to the mentioned "for" loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

I am currently learning loops in java and I have tried the following code:

```
public class Dummy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int c=0, b=150; true; c--, b++) {
            if(c==5){
                System.out.println("c is equal to 5");
                System.out.println("value of b :"+b);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that it would run infinitely as `c--` would be infinitely negative and will never be equal to 5 but I ended up getting the following output:

```
    c is equal to 5
    value of b :145
```

Can anyone explain why am I getting this output?

Comment: To see what is happening, try to print `b` and `c` at every iteration.

Comment: A int type is signed type. When it hits the minimum, let's say 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111, it would be overflow with anther substraction.